# How can I use mysqli_fetch_array value from outside of if condition

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need a solution for update data. with current code i am getting $product_name, $product_des, $product_price undefined variable error. how can solve this? Since i cant get those variable value from outside of first if condition then how can i run update query?

```
echo '<form action="" method="post">ID Number:<input type="number" name="id_number" value="number"><br><br><input type="submit" value="Search Product" name="id_number_submit">';

if (isset($_POST['id_number_submit'])) {
    $id_number = $_POST['id_number'];

    $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id='$id_number'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($q);

    if (empty($row)) {
        echo "Error: Invalid product id";
    }
    else{

    $product_name = $row['product_name'];
    $product_des = $row['product_des'];
    $product_price = $row['product_price'];


echo '<br><br><input type="number" name="product_price" value="'.$product_price.'">';
echo '<br><br><input type="text" name="product_name" value="'.$product_name.'">';
echo '<br><br><textarea rows="8" cols="100" name="product_des">'.$product_des.'</textarea><br>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="save_changes_submit">';

    }
  }


if (isset($_POST['save_changes_submit'])) {
    $c_product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
    $c_product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
    $c_product_des = $_POST['product_des'];

    $q2 = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE product SET product_name='$c_product_name', product_price='$c_product_price', product_des='$c_product_des' WHERE product_name='$product_name', product_price='$product_price', product_des='$product_des'");

    if ($q2>0) {
        echo "Successfully updated!";
    }else{echo "Error: Failed to update";}
}

echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Initialize them as empty strings before the `if` statement.

Comment: 1. why don't you query by `$id_number` in first place? 2. `$_POST['id_number_submit']` is not set when trying to update. So eighter ask for `$_POST['id_number']` directly, or move getting the data to a seperate function.

Comment: 3. use prepared statements. You're vulnerable to sql-injections! And sanitize all user-input.

Comment: What is the output of the $q? Print the output as, echo '<pre>'; print_r($q); die;

Comment: 4. get away from having logic and output in one 'flow'. This is way it's getting complicated.

Comment: For one thing, kindly notice that your existing code, upon encountering an empty query *("invalid product id")*, **keeps going!**  Also, consider what will happen when someone named Bobby Tables POSTs:  `product_id="4; drop table product"`to your second query  ... if you've got the wrong ini defaults set ...